# Can't commit/update file in Xcode editor (SVN)

Tags: xcode, svn

I'm having problems with Xcode's built in SVN manager.

I checked out a remote SVN repository and I want to commit the changes while I'm working in Xcode's editor. As seen on the screenshot, it shows the correct SVN flag in the Organiser window and also in the editor sidebar (M for modified etc.), but when I try to commit from within the editor, I get the error:

> The operation could not be performed because no valid working copies were found.

Although commiting/updating etc. works fine in the Organiser window…

Any ideas why?

[image: Xcode SVN Error]

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue recently.

The solution for me was a simple restart of Xcode, and after that all the files were noted as being updatable via the right click "Source Control >" menu.

Comment: It doesn't work form me. I have this error "since ever", I restarted Xcode hundreds of times…

Comment: Me too in 4.6.2 wtf? Sometimes in the past, relaunch helped, but rarely.

Comment: Xcode is more bipolar than my ex. I hate to waste time fixing stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this myself today when trying out Git with Xcode for the first time. I created two demo projects with the "create a local git repository" option and they had the same problem. I was able to commit from the organizer window, but the main Xcode file view didn't seem to recognize git at all.

After quitting and restarting, I created a third demo with the git option, and the main window recognized the changes right off the bat - i.e showed the "M" beside a modified file.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I read that solution already in another posting, but I'm working with remote SVN repositories and I guess this is not related with that git issue…

Answer (score 0):

I think Xcode subversion version is different from repositary version.
if you use other svn management tools like "cornerstone", you have to check versions.

Check subversion's version on Terminal

1.xcode subversion 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/svn --version

2.installed subversion
/usr/bin/svn --version

3.port installed version
/opt/local/bin/svn --version

check these versions and upgrade Xcode's svn binary.

This is what i did.

```
$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
$ mkdir svn_backup
$ mv svn* svn_backup/.
$ ln -s /opt/local/bin/svn* .
```

and restart Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it's exactly the same version as in `/usr/bin/svn`…